# Entity Framework Core throws when using Include with parameterized input

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

In EF Core 2.2.6 I need to construct a dynamic query with parameterized input. I start by constructing the statement:

```
var rawSql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM dbo.Projects ");
var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

rawSql.Append(string.Format("WHERE ProjectId < @param"));
sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", "20"));
```

Then I execute it:

```
var projects = await _context.Projects.FromSql(rawSql.ToString(), sqlParameters.ToArray())
    .ToListAsync();
```

This works. But if I add an `Include` it throws

> ArgumentException: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection`

```
var projects = await _context.Projects.FromSql(rawSql.ToString(), sqlParameters.ToArray())
    .Include(p => p.Managers)
    .ToListAsync();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could use `IQueryable<Project> query=_context.Projects; query = query.Where(p=>p.ProjectId=20)` to add the WHERE clause at runtime. As for the error itself, it could be a bug in EF Core 2.2, or an attempt to reuse the same parameter list. Are you building the same query and list each time? Or reusing them?

Comment: Add [logging to the context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) to see what's happening. I suspect the [DbLoggerCategory.Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbloggercategory.query?view=efcore-3.0) is relevant here, as the problem occurs before the query gets executed